# How to check if an argument is a file or a directory in R?

Tags: python, r, if-statement

I am quite familiar with the python equivalents 'os.path.isfile(*path*)' and 'os.path.isdir(*path*)' which say if *path* is a file or a directory.

So far, I have failed to find a simple and straightforward way to do this in R and it seems that even Google has never heard about this either !

Does anybody can beat Google and tell me what is the simplest way in R just to check if a given argument is a file, a directory or none of them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on the comment:

```
file.info("/etc")
##      size isdir mode               mtime               ctime
## /etc 3638  TRUE  755 2015-07-22 10:51:58 2015-07-22 10:51:58
##                    atime uid gid uname grname
## /etc 2015-08-01 08:11:43   0   0  root  wheel

file.info("/etc/hosts")
##              size isdir mode               mtime               ctime
## /etc/hosts 787448 FALSE  644 2015-07-19 17:34:59 2015-07-19 17:34:59
##                          atime uid gid uname grname
## /etc/hosts 2015-08-06 12:30:26   0   0  root  wheel

file_test("-f", "/etc/hosts") # is a file and not a dir
## [1] TRUE

file_test("-d", "/etc") # is a dir
## [1] TRUE

dir.exists("/etc") # R 3.2.0+
## [1] TRUE

file.exists("/etc/hosts")
## [1] TRUE

Sys.readlink("/etc") # will return something if it's a symbolic link
## [1] "private/etc"

Sys.readlink("/tmp")
## [1] "private/tmp"

Sys.readlink("/bin") # or "" if not
## [1] ""
```

Comment: Congratulation @hrbrmstr, you did beat Google !! You know what nobody knows ! Anyway, thank you very much this helped me so well.